# Create multiple pipe in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

For the pipe communication of multiprocess,  could we create multiple pipe communication?

For example, I had 2 script , main function and test function. My main function have 2 object : car and plane. While , test function have two object car2 and plane2. Could I create communication pipe between car2 and car and plane2 and plane separately?

Below is what I think , but not sure if I do it correctly or not . I think it not because I have some error in passing the communication in pipe.

```
 from time import sleep
from random import random
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pipe
 
# generate work
def test(connection):
    print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
    # generate work
    for i in range(10):
        # generate a value
        value = random()
        # block
        sleep(value)
        # send data
        connection.send(value)
    # all done
    connection.send(None)
    print('Sender: Done', flush=True)
 
# consume work
def main(connection):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        item = connection.recv()
        # report
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        # check for stop
        if item is None:
            break
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)
 
# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the pipe
    plane, plane1 = Pipe()
    car,car2 = Pipe()
    # start the sender
    sender_process = Process(target=main, args=(plane,car,))
    sender_process.start()
    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=test,args=(plane2,car2,))
    receiver_process.start()
    # wait for all processes to finish
    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

Comment: you only have multiple syntax errors.

Comment: Oh, thank you , I will fix it . For multiple pipe , do the way I approach correct ?

Comment: i don't know, it depends on why do you have multiple pipes, there's nothing wrong with having multiple pipes, but they will introduce extra complexity if they are not needed.

Comment: I need multiple pipes because I want to transmitted multiple object data at the same time across both process. Since my project is company project which not allow to put code here , so I use an example to try and test the multiple pipes.I try to find example using multiple on google but could not find any.

Comment: Your code only seems to be using the connection instances from a single Pipe (it's hard to say because you never corrected your code). Moreover, if you needed to send and receive in both child processes you would still need only one Pipe because by default it is full duplex meaning a connection cam be used for both sending and receiving.

Comment: I agree duplex could be use for send and receive . However, if I have 2 variable in main called mouse and cat and want to communicate data to mouse2 and cat2 ( mouse communicate with mouse2  and cat communicate with cat2 ) at the same time. I think multiple pipe would be good solution.I also agree my above code did not distinguish what pipe belong to what pair of object .So how do I let the program know with pipe belong to mouse and mouse2 , cat to cat2?